# property in properties file isn't changed

Tags: java, properties

I have a properties file that i create manualy.
  I can to get the propert in the file by getProperty() function, but I can't change it!
  I try with setProperty() function, but the file isn't changed.

can u help me?

thanks!

zipi

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the properties file again using `store()` (of which there are two variants). The `setProperty()` method changes the value of property stored in memory, not the value of the property in the file the properties were loaded from.

For further reading see the [Properties Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

SetProperty() will only set the property during the runtime. It will not go and override your file property. It wont modify your file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call something like 
    `prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"), null);`after calling `prop.setProperty` method? Because it's the way you flush changes to file.

Without calling store changes are visible only in application memory.

Comment: yes.I write : p.store(new FileOutputStream("test.properties"), null); and it doesnt change the file

Comment: maybe the path is not correct? the file is in the src folder, what is the correct path to it?

Comment: Path to your file should be src/test.properties.